# Findstr : Search a string in files without extension

Tags: windows, batch, findstr

I want to search a string in files **without** extension.

I've tried:

```
findstr /s /m /c:"the_word_i_need_to_find" *
```

But this command search in files with **any** extension.

Comment: Have you tried using `*.`?

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I want to search a string in files without extension.

```
findstr /s /m /c:"the_word_i_need_to_find" *
```

`*` will match any files (and potentially directories as well.

`*.` will match files with no extension.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Wildcards - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html)